# Error while splitting index.js file in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to split my **index.js** file in multiple files. I'd like to count the number of children in a database reference. Previously my **index.js** file was

```
exports.updateUserBookCount = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userID}/Books/{bookID}')
      .onWrite(async (change,context)=>{

        const collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent;
        const userID = context.params.userID;
        const countRef = admin.database().ref(`/UserInfo/${userID}/usersBooks`);
        console.log("book counter : "+collectionRef);

        const bookList = await collectionRef.once('value');
        return await countRef.set(bookList.numChildren());

      });
```

I created new file **counter.js**  it's

```
//counter.js
exports.userBookCount = function(change,context,admin){
    const collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent;
    const userID = context.params.userID;
    const countRef = admin.database().ref(`/UserInfo/${userID}/usersBooks`);
    console.log("book counter : "+collectionRef);

    const bookList = await collectionRef.once('value');
    return await countRef.set(bookList.numChildren());
}
```

Then I changed **index.js** like

```
//index.js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const counter = require('./counter');
exports.updateUserBookCount = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userID}/Books/{bookID}')
      .onWrite(async (change,context)=>{
         counter.userBookCount(change,context,admin);
      });
```

But I'm getting error  **in counter.js 9:28  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token collectionRef** while deploying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on your structure, but I'm guessing you just want to be able to split up the files for code organization? If so, here's how I would have structured it:

```js
//index.js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
admin.initializeApp()

const counter = require('./counter.js')

exports.updateUserBookCount = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userID}/Books/{bookID}').onWrite(counter);
```

```js
//counter.js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

//This function becomes counter in your index.js - you don't get counter.userBookCount because you have a single export from this file
module.exports = (change, context) => {
  // rest of your logic
}

//If you really want counter.userBookCount because you'll have other functions here, export multiple functions like this:
module.exports = {
  userBookCount: (change, context) => {
    // rest of your logic
  },
  someOtherBookFunction: (change, context) => { ... }
}
```